# Unable to create UIImage from filepath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage, relationships

I'm trying to create UIImages from a list of Core Data saved file locations. Here is my code:

```
ontracFullScreenImageViewController *sectional = [viewControllerDictionary objectForKey:@"Sectional Appendices"];
        sectional.dataObject = self.dataObject.dataPack;
        //sectional.imageArray = [[dataObject.sectionalDiagrams allObjects] mutableCopy];



        if ([dataObject.sectionalDiagrams count] != 0 || dataObject.sectionalDiagrams == nil){
        NSLog(@"dataObject.sectionalDiagrams %@", dataObject.sectionalDiagrams);
            for (SectionalDiagram *section in dataObject.sectionalDiagrams) {
                NSLog(@"section %@", section);
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:section.locationString];

                NSLog(@"image %@", image);

                if(image != nil){
                    [sectional.imageArray addObject:image];
                    [sectional.imageLinks addObject:section.locationString];
                }



            }
            //[sectional loadScreen];

        }
        else
        {
            [self removeMenuOptionForString:@"Sectional Appendices"];
        }
        [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Loaded the Sectional Appendices"];
```

The log shows the following objects with the Core Data request:

```
with objects {(
<SectionalDiagram: 0x14fdde40> (entity: SectionalDiagram; id: 0x14fddb10 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/SectionalDiagram/p15> ; data: {
dataObject = "0x14d29820 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/DataObject/p17>";
locationString = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/43B4BC10-58AA-45DE-9A3B-E90A3A08DC2D/Documents/coss@on-trac.co.uk_A2rA2d_sectional_appendix_947735_2147483647_image.png";
}),
<SectionalDiagram: 0x14fddbd0> (entity: SectionalDiagram; id: 0x14fddaf0 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/SectionalDiagram/p13> ; data: {
dataObject = "0x14d29820 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/DataObject/p17>";
locationString = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/43B4BC10-58AA-45DE-9A3B-E90A3A08DC2D/Documents/coss@on-trac.co.uk_NpH3Yg_sectional_appendix_947735_2147483647_image.png";
}),
<SectionalDiagram: 0x14fdde10> (entity: SectionalDiagram; id: 0x14fddb00 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/SectionalDiagram/p14> ; data: {
dataObject = "0x14d29820 <x-coredata://BC0EFCDC-FAA8-404D-A9DE-33AEE09AD1C6/DataObject/p17>";
locationString = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/43B4BC10-58AA-45DE-9A3B-E90A3A08DC2D/Documents/coss@on-trac.co.uk_jGKgWx_sectional_appendix_947735_2147483647_image.png";
})
```

I have checked and all three of the images exist on the device but it keeps coming back as null.

Comment: There's nothing in your post that indicates a Core Data fault. Where does that come in?

Comment: Don't store the full path to the file.  Just store the filename.  To get the image, lookup the path for the documents directory, and append the filename.

Comment: @TomHarrington You're right! I realised the fault was simply trying to log the relationship info too early.

Comment: @pbasdf thanks, is that just advice or are you suggesting that might be the issue here?

Comment: I think it might be the issue, the path to the docs directory can change, particularly when you are rebuilding the app.

Comment: @pbasdf you should make that an answer, it's almost certainly the reason

Comment: You could check by logging the path to the docs directory and comparing with the paths you've got.  I think that weird long hex number (43B4BC10-58AA-45DE-9A3B-E90A3A08DC2D) might be different.

Comment: Ok so i've just checked the log for the images as they're saved and they match what is being searched for at this stage :/

Comment: pbasdf is right. You can't store full path to file, only last path beginning from application documents directory, path part "43B4BC10-58AA-45DE-9A3B-E90A3A08DC2D" can be different only in couple of symbols, and this part can change even after application restart

Comment: @jampez77 If you log `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]` just before you log `dataObject.sectionalDiagrams`, do the paths match?

Comment: Thank you guys, I've got it working now by using the NSFileManager URL as suggested to get the image files. If someone wants to put an answer up i'll happily accept it :)

Comment: @jampez77 Thanks - added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the path to the Documents directory can change, particularly when rebuilding the app.  So don't store the full path to the file. Just store the filename. To get the image, lookup the path for the documents directory, using

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]
```

and append the filename.